# Azure SignalR Service slow on first message

Tags: azure, azure-signalr

Azure SignalR Service, hosted version, is slow on first message. My setup is two Azure Functions, one for sub and one for pub. (just like the Microsoft example).  Not sure if it is SignalR or the Azure Functions that cause this slow startup.  How do I fix it? It creates a bad user experience for my users right at the start of their chat.

Here are the functions two functions used ...

subscribe function

```
"disabled": false,
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    },
    {
      "type": "signalRConnectionInfo",
      "name": "connectionInfo",
      "hubName": "chat",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ]
}
```

messages functions

```
{
  "disabled": false,
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    },
    {
      "type": "signalR",
      "name": "signalRMessages",
      "hubName": "chat",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ]
}
```

I expect the first message to be just as fast as the subsequent messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No responses so I switched to PubNub. SignalR Service was too unreliable.  Closing this.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out to us in support. Glad you were able to get what you needed in short time. Cheers!